# How can I access or assign custom currency symbols when format method is called using money gem?

Tags: ruby, symbols, currency

I have a list of currency codes that I need to display specific currency values for and have found that some are available in [alternate_symbols from money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/f2d455fff488d06744f666412dc1cb5eb07d211d/config/currency_iso.json#L7). I can't figure out how to access those when using the format method, though, and also need to override a handful. For example, for CAD, I need to display the second symbol - CAD$ - but for SRD, I need to display SRD$ which doesn't exist in alternate_symbols array for that currency.

I'm looking to use i18n to specify these currencies since some are more custom.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to override the necessary languages.

```
josh_dollar = {
  :priority        => 1,
  :iso_code        => "USD",
  :iso_numeric     => "840",
  :name            => "United States Dollar",
  :symbol          => "Josh",
  :subunit         => "Cent",
  :subunit_to_unit => 100,
  :separator       => ".",
  :delimiter       => ","
}

Money::Currency.register(josh_dollar)
josh_dollar = Money.new(1000,"USD")
josh_dollar.format
#=> "10.00 Josh"
```